# Using Windows Command in .cmd to test if 32 bit or 64 bit and run a command

Tags: windows, if-statement, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am writing a script that find a registry value and returns that value to the windows command prompt screen and also adds that to a .txt file. I am to a point where I need to also test to see if the machine is 32 bit or 64 bit so that I know which command to use to find the value I need in the registry.

I am looking for logic along the lines of what I have written below:

If 32 bit then (run this command)
else
(run this command)

I am hoping to not have to have any text files or anything else required for this script to work. Below is the code I have so far. Due to the registry location being private, I changed the location to a made up location. (Note: I do have a text file this script reads from that I insert the names of computers and servers. So far the code I have works but with 2 registry find commands I am obviously not getting right results when its checking a 32 bit machine for a 64 bit registry location)

```
@echo off

Setlocal

::sets the ldt variable to the local date and time in yyyymmdd_hhmmss
for /f "skip=1" %%c in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime') do set ldt=%%c
set ldt=%ldt:~0,8%_%ldt:~8,6%


::searches for computer names in servers.txt and then calls server sub routine. Once it goes back to the for loop it moves onto the next line in servers.txt
for /f %%c in (servers.txt) do (
set server=%%c
call:server
)
pause
goto:eof

--------------------------------------------------------------------
:server
set stamp=%date% at %time%
set DateTime=%stamp%

::Tests for a good ping, if no ping then move onto next machine
ping -n 1 -w 250 %server% > nul 
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
  ECHO No Ping on %server%
  ECHO No Ping on %server% >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
  goto:eof
)
call:screen
call:log
goto:eof

--------------------------------------------------------------------
:screen
echo.
echo Computer name: %server%
reg query "\\%server%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Registry Folder1\Information\" /V "Datavalue" | FIND "Datavalue"
reg query "\\%server%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Registry Folder1\Information" /V "Datavalue" | FIND "Datavalue"
echo.
goto:eof

--------------------------------------------------------------------
:log
echo. >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
echo Registry value for %server% on %stamp% >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
reg query "\\%server%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Registry Folder1\Information\" /V "Datavalue" | FIND "Datavalue" >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
reg query "\\%server%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Registry Folder1\Information" /V "Datavalue" | FIND "Datavalue" >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
echo. >>AuditScript_%ldt%.txt
goto:eof

--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you could probably use `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`:, as explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx. According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/5a316848-1ec3-4d01-a395-7c5b17756239, corresponding registry key (so you can query it remotely) is: "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"

Comment: still having trouble trying to get this to work with windows command but still trying. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%x in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE') do set CPU=%%x
echo CPU Architecture: %CPU%
if "%CPU:~-2%"=="64" (
  echo Do This
) else (
  echo Do That
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture /value') do (
  set arch=%%a
)

if "%arch%"=="32-bit" (
  rem do some
) else (
  rem do other
)

endlocal
```

Comment: I ended up using another method but thanks for the help. I didn't know you could do it using wmic. I up voted you for helping though, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

via cmd you can check the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` variable like so:

`echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` this will output `x86` or `x64` depending on the OS

so you can use something along the lines of:

```
@echo off

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
goto :x86
) else (
goto :x64
)

:x86
start "foo.exe"
goto :eof

:x64
start "bar.exe"
goto :eof
```

Comment: +1 A perfectly reasonable and actually the most efficient method. I didn't expect to be selected myself fiddeling with the registry like I did. 8-D

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Installed OS
Set _Bitness=64
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
  IF NOT DEFINED PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set _Bitness=32
  )
Echo Operating System is %_Bitness% bit
```

I think that works